# Hölder Space Definition

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, holder-spaces

At the beginiing of the defintion of Hölder spaces and the Hölder space norm. They start defining the first term of the Hölder norm as follows:

If $u:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and continuous, we write $||u||_{C(\bar{U})} := \text{sup}_{x \in U}|u(x)|$. How do we know that $u \in C(\bar{U})$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With these assumptions, $u$ does not belong necessarily to $C(\overline U)$. For example, take $U:=(0,1)$ and $u(x):=\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)$. This is a continuous bounded function, but since $u((\pi n)^{-1})=0$ and $u((\pi n+\pi/2)^{-1})=1$, we cannot extend it as a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes that's what I find strange. Since writing $||u||_{C(\bar{U})}$ certainly implies $u \in C(\bar{U})$. Do you think the idea is that the Holder space $C^{k,\gamma}(U)$ only has a semi norm but cannot be assigned a norm but it is required to extend it to $C^{k,\gamma}(\bar{U}) \subset C^{k}(\bar{U})$ to assign a norm ?

Comment: Yes, that's what is used since if $u$ is Hölder continuous, it can be extended to $\overline U$ (it's in particular uniformly continuous).

Comment: Why do you think it is that the norm cannot be defined on $C^{k,\gamma}(U)$? Why are normed holder spaces limited to $C^{k,\gamma}(\bar{U})$ where the norm is $||u||_{C^{k,\gamma}(\bar{U})} := \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k}||D^{\alpha}u||_{C(\bar{U})} + \sum_{|\alpha| =k}[D^{\alpha}u]_{C^{0,\gamma}\bar{U}}$ where $||u||_{C(\bar{U})} := \text{sup}_{x \in U}|u(x)|$ and $[u]_{C^{0,\gamma}(\bar{U})} := \text{sup}_{x,y \in U}\{\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{\gamma}}\}$?

Comment: This norm _is_ well defined for the Hölder continuous maps (and those for which the derivatives are Hölder continuous). What do you mean by limited to $C^{k,\gamma}(\overline U)$?

Comment: Okay but for $u \in C^{k,\gamma}(\bar{U})$ it is only required that $D^{\alpha}u$ be Holder continuous for $|\alpha| = k $, $u$ doesn't have to be. But to answer your question I just want to know why the definition of normed Holder Spaces requires that $u \in C^{k, \gamma}(\bar{U})$ and not in just  $u \in C^{k, \gamma}(U)$, if it is the case that the norm can only be defined for functions in $u \in C^{k, \gamma}(\bar{U})$ then do you maybe know the reason why?